# Inverter objeto dentro de uma table

Tags: asp.net

Meu objetivo é inverter dois objetos de posição quando selecionado um elemento no dropdown

**Exemplo:**
Por default, quando se abre a pagina o componente `dropdown` tem dois elementos "Destino" e "Origem"

Esses componentes abre um `SELECT (Território)` e uma outra `DROPDOWN (Pais)`.
Quando eu selecionar no dropdow (primeiro mencionado) "Destino" e "Importação"
os dois componentes `SELECT (territorio)` e `DROPDOWN (pais)` tem que inverter, tipo ... `DROPDOWN (pais) ==Direita` e `SELECT (territorio)==Esquerda`

```
<tr id="trTerritorioPais" runat="server">
    <td>
        <b>Territorialidade:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="slctTerritorialidade" runat="server" onchange="ExibirTD(this.value)">
            <option value="RegiaoBR">Região BR</option>
            <option value="UF">UF</option>
            <option value="RegPlanMG">Região de Planejamento MG</option>
            <option value="MunicipioMG">Município MG</option>
        </select>
        <b title="Campo Obrigatório"> * </b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>País:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList Width="200px" ID="ddlPais" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <b title="Campo Obrigatório"> * </b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Cabe ressaltar também que tenho valores (dados) no banco de dados, preciso fazer isso sem alterar o banco.

Comment: Noto que os "Selects" que você quer inverter estão em "td's" separadas. O que você quer é trocar o conteúdo de uma "td" pelo da outra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se compreendi bem você pode fazer isso com jQuery.

Se ainda não está usando essa biblioteca basta referenciar assim:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Um exemplo de como ficaria o código:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var htmlColunaA = $('td.a').html();
    var htmlColunaB = $('td.b').html();

    $(document).on("change", ".classeDoPrimeiroSelect", function(){
        $('td.a').html(htmlColunaB);
        $('td.b').html(htmlColunaA);
    });
});

</script>
```

O que esse código faz é ao escolher um valor no select da classe "classeDoPrimeiroSelect" você pega o código das duas colunas e depois as coloca em colunas invertidas.

Esse código funciona com o seguinte html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <select class="classeDoPrimeiroSelect">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a">Bola</td>
        <td class="b">Casa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Portanto você terá que adaptar ao seu html adicionando as classes necessárias.

Fiddle de exemplo dessa inversão: http://jsfiddle.net/johnflaster/qEFJ6/

Comment: Joao Paulo, bom dia ... Sua solução me atendeu mesmo, quando eu seleciono um elemento no primeiro dropdown, os dois objetos trocam de posição, valeu mesmo!!!!! estou aplicando no projeto agora. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom! Qualquer dúvida posta ai no site. E não esqueça de marcar como resolvido.

Comment: sim, estou só aplicando a solução aqui e vou fechar como resolvido. Valeu mais uma vez.